# Java Vertical Layout?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, miglayout

I need to position a JLabel over some JButtons, vertically, like a game menu. They should all be centered. I already downloaded MigLayout, but I'm not sure how to use that, so I just want a way to position my components vertically and centered, MigLayout or not. Also, I don't want to use a IDE GUI designer.

Comment: *"I don't want to use a IDE GUI designer"*  +1 :)  Such designers *can* increase productivity for a developer that already understands the layouts and how to combine them.  Until you become proficient in core J2SE layouts (+ perhaps a 3rd party layout or 3) it is less than helpful to be trying to design a GUI while fighting the GUI designer.

Comment: The problem is, I already wrote all my GUI stuff by hand (except for this), and I don't want to revise it will provide a big benefit.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You might use a (single column) [`GridLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html) or [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html) for this.  See [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) & [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more tips, ideas and working source.

Comment: @Jeffrey That was probably because I posted the reply before editing to add links.  ;)

Comment: BoxLayout works well for buttons, but not for JLabels...my JLabel is still aligned to the left.

Comment: The problem is that the JLabel extends all the way across the frame(determined by drawing a border).

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out by setting the JLabel maximum size. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 13):

You should use [`BoxLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html). Here a basic example

```
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class VerticalPanel extends JPanel {

    public VerticalPanel() {
        super();
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            add(new JLabel("Label n°" + i));
        }
    }

}
```