# Wrap element java swing

Tags: java, swing

I have this example where the panels(with title,desc and button) are placed next to one another[image]

This is the code

```
 public class Example extends JFrame {

    Example() {

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            add(new MyPanel());

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        MyPanel() {

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(new JLabel("title", SwingConstants.CENTER), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
            add(new JLabel("<html>WWWWWW WWWWWWW<p>WWWWWWWWW<p>RRRRRRR RRRRR RRRRRRR"));
            add(new JButton("Details"), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Example());
    }
}
```

how to wrap the panels every time?

[image]

Comment: *"how to wrap every time?"*  Wrap what, exactly?  The title+details+button components?  The text in the labels?  Something else?

Comment: ... and wrap in what way? Graphically with a border? Or programmatically with some sort of wrapper class? Please clarify your problem and your question for us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels see the image in the question

Comment: Just use a different layout manager -- please read up on them. A `new GridLayout(0, 1)` for variable number of rows and 1 column would work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Vertical Layout?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950885/java-vertical-layout)

Comment: Also look at [these relevant Google links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+place+components+vertically+site:http://stackoverflow.com/&start=10).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a different layout manager -- please read up on them. A `new GridLayout(0, 1)` for variable number of rows and 1 column would work. Also consider using a BoxLayout that uses the constraint `BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS`.